# Prove that $(f, g) = \int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t) \,\mathrm dt$ defines an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

> Let $V$ be the vector space of all continuous functions $f\colon [-1,1]\to\Bbb R$. Prove that $(f, g) = \int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t) \,\mathrm dt$ defines an inner product.

I'm fairly new to inner products and further linear algebra and am just trying to wrap my head around this

I understand that for $(f, g) = \int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t) \,\mathrm dt$ to be an inner product it must satisfy it being symmetric and the positive definiteness.

Where i have;
$(x,y) = (y,x)$ for all $x,y \in V$

and

$(x,x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in V$ and $(x,x)=0$ only if $x$ is the zero vector

I assumed it would simply be plugging in but im not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$(f,g)=\int_{-1}^{1} f(t)g(t) dt=\int_{-1}^{1} g(t)f(t) dt=(g,f)$$ for every $f,g$.
And we have
$$(f,f)=\int_{-1}^{1} (f(t))^2 dt\geq 0$$
for every f by $(f(t))^2\geq 0$ and the monotony of the integral.
We now have to show that $(f,f)=0$ implies $f=0$.
It is standard lemma that for a continuous function $g\geq 0$ we have
$$\int_{a}^{b} g(t) dt=0\Rightarrow g=0.$$
We can apply this lemma to $f^2$ ($f^2$ is continuous, because $f$ is continuous and $f^2\geq 0$ is clear) and get
$$0=(f,f)=\int_{-1}^{1} (f(t))^2 dt\Rightarrow f^2=0\Rightarrow f=0.$$
If you don't know the lemma, I can give you a prove for it.

Comment: ok im not entirely sure why but that completely flew over my head, it seems simple enough thank you!

Comment: +1 For completeness, a positive continuous function $g$ with $g(x_0) > 0$, must be at least $g(x_0) / 2 > 0$ on some $\delta$-wide neighbourhood, using continuity at $x_0$ with $\varepsilon = g(x_0) / 2$. Thus, by the monotonicity of the integral, the integral of $g$ must be at least $\delta g(x_0) > 0$.